# Replace word for blank using sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a file that contains mysql grants for all the users. Looks something like this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'web_user'@'10.16.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*288A8C32D8C898U779EDA321A6CD6525DB2D3166';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE ON `users`.* TO 'web_user'@'10.16.%';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `zip`.* TO 'web_user'@'10.16.%';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'alarms'@'10.16.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*E8DEF50F129E0DAF1113382944F603677BA11260';
GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE ON `users`.* TO 'alarms'@'10.16.%';
...
...
...
```

Using sed I need to remove the passwords. I should look something like this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'web_user'@'10.16.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, EXECUTE ON `users`.* TO 'web_user'@'10.16.%';
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `zip`.* TO 'web_user'@'10.16.%';
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'alarms'@'10.16.%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD
GRANT SELECT, EXECUTE ON `users`.* TO 'alarms'@'10.16.%';
...
...
...
```

Comment: Without trailing `;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's/identified by password.*/identified by password/i'
```

Comment: you're changing the case of IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD. And yours is a GNU solution.

Comment: Case is insignificant for SQL keywords. What GNU extension am I using?

Comment: The i modifier to regular-expression matching is a GNU extension which makes sed match regexp in a case-insensitive manner. Your solution won't work on Mac

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
sed 's/\(PASSWORD\).*$/\1/' file
```

If you want to write changes to this `file` just add `-i` for your `sed`